WPF Window Icon is not displayed properly after DPI change in DPI aware app
I am struggling with a strange behaviour. I have a WPF DPI aware application. I have 3 resource dictionaries with images for different DPI levels (96, 120, 144). On DpiChanged event I can change the resource dictionary for appropriate DPI. All the images in my app are set as DynamicResource, so they change after swaping the resource dictionary. All this works fine except window icon. The icon also changes, but somehow its size in pixels does not. Contrary of the other images it's blurry.
When the application starts with 96DPI settings and is changed to 144DPI, the icon stays the same size, but gets blurry.
When the application starts with 144DPI settings and is changed to 96DPI, the icon becomes blurry and even smaller.
This is the output - the window has an icon and an image, they both have the same DynamicResource - BitmapImage.

Thank you.
PS: My OS is Win 10

Could you share your test project to see what is happening?

There it is: https://github.com/nytmo/WpfWindowIconSample

So you use PNG file for title bar icon. I think you might have better result with properly created ICO file.

@emoacht Sadly, it's not working (see the last commit and kindly try). The ICO has 2 sizes inside - 16x16 (for 96 DPI) and 24x24 (for 144 DPI). It can contain only sizes that are multiple of 8, so it can't contain the size of 20x20 (for 120 DPI). Nevertheless, it's not working, after switching from 96 DPI to 144 DPI, the size 16x16 is still shown.

If a PNG file is set, it will be converted internally so that it can be handled like ordinary ICO file. Track interncal code of UpdateIcon. So if the conversion is not satisfactory, I think the only solution for you is to create the custom title bar where you can use the image as you wish.
